# (Pgrouting) Finding the best path within some maximal length

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting

Is it possible to find the best path (where cost is not length) with the length limit? For example, find the best path that is shorter than 10km? I currently use pgr_astar from Pgrouting to find the best path, so is there any function/trick in Pgrouting which is able to handle this?

Comment: cost is not length, cost is just cost which you have assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate which links are accessible within 10 km (shortest path), delete the rest and then calculate path according to your more generic cost.

Comment: When using this : 

    SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost
            FROM pgr_astar(
                    'SELECT id, source, target, cost, x1, y1, x2, y2 FROM edge_table',
                    7, 12, false, false
            );

alter inner SELECT with WHERE clause which limits data to 10km from start node (7)